# How to use custom UI for swashbuckle

Tags: swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am trying to use a custom swashbuckle index.html for our .net core project. I followed the doc and done this:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.IndexStream = () => GetType().Assembly
        .GetManifestResourceStream("CustomUIIndex.Swagger.index.html"); // requires file to be added as an embedded resource
});
```

The custom index page (based on the default index.html) is loaded, but I can see the html page outputted these:

```
%(HeadContent)
 .....
window.onload = function () {
            var configObject = JSON.parse('%(ConfigObject)');
            var oauthConfigObject = JSON.parse('%(OAuthConfigObject)');
```

So looks like the contents %(ConfigObject) or %(HeadContent) are not replaced. What should I do to get the custom index page work properly?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i mark all codes in window.onload and
the image of html source code :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/haHWm.png